# I want to set note attribute in Shopify product page when some one click on buy it now button

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I set the attribute using Shopify update.js ajax API and it is worked for checkout using cart page.

How I added the attribute is as follow.

```
jQuery.post('/cart/update.js', "attributes['attribute_Key']=attribute_Value");
```

but if someone purchase product using buy it now button I am not able to get this attribute in order.

[image]

I want the attribute in both ways.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ajaxify your "add to cart" or "buy it now" button.
Make sure when it's clicked the form isn't submitted then add your logic to the click event.